# SQL Server Database Tools on a Mac

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, sql-server-data-tools

I have a DB project which relies on SQL Server Database tools.  I am trying to work on it on a Mac.  The rest of the project is in .NET Core so that all works well.  The database project throws an error on `dotnet restore`

> /Users/mborozdin/src/ethos/FileRepository/src/FileRepository.Database/FileRepository.Database.sqlproj(63,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v10.0/SSDT/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Is there an alternative to SSDT which seems to be only available on Windows?

Comment: SSDT is only available for Windows at the moment, which is required for SSIS/SSRS/SSAS development.

Comment: There are other tools, like SQL Operations Studio, which runs on Win/Mac/Linux. But SSDT proper, you're out of luck. Use a VM.

Answer (score 5):

When you develop on the Mac,
You will put your SQL Server on the docker or Virtual Machine.

In other to connect, You need SQL Operations Studio for the Mac
[Download Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download)

Comment: Note: 'SQL Operations Studio' has been renamed to 'Azure Data Studio'

Answer (score 4):

*Is there an alternative to SSDT which seems to be only available on Windows?*

The alternative is [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is). As for:

> [SQL Database Projects extension](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2020/07/15/the-july-2020-release-of-azure-data-studio-is-now-available/)
>
> The SQL Database Projects extension brings project-based database development, well-known in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), to the cross-platform Azure Data Studio experience. From this early insiders release you can create, build, and publish a project from scratch or an existing database.
>
> https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/11105

Comment: hows the experience using ADS? when using it back in '21 I found the experience poor when compared to developing with VS. Have you setup CI/CD using Devops / Jenkins / Ansible or github actions?